# How to combine multiple row data based on relationships

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

So I have two columns with group_user_id and array of user_ids. End goal is to combine user_id_list array based on the transitive relationships between different user_ids.

For example, currently I've data in following format

```
group_user_id              user_id_list
    123                        123
                               456
                               345
                               234
    567                        567
                               678
                               456
```

and I'm trying to achieve this, based on relationship **123 - 456 - 567** and hence joining user_id_list from both group_user_id 123 and 567. PS: order of user_ids in user_id_list doesn't matter.

```
group_user_id              user_id_list
    123                        123
                               456
                               345
                               234
                               567
                               678
    567                        567
                               123
                               345
                               234
                               678
                               456
```

I understand this might be much simpler with something like graphDB. But, I'm stuck with google-bigquery

Comment: This requires recursion or looping.  BigQuery does not support that directly through `select`, but you can write a loop using the scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

I've only spent a few minutes looking at this but hopefully this is what you're looking for and I haven't completely miss-understood your question.

You do a self-join on the `user_id_list` column then join back onto the original table with the new `group_id` field from the join:

```sql
SELECT distinct
  v1.group_id v1_group_id,
  v3.user_id_list v3_user_id_list
FROM
  simon_test.test_data v1
JOIN simon_test.test_data v2
  on v1.user_id_list = v2.user_id_list
join simon_test.test_data v3
  on v2.group_id = v3.group_id
order by v1_group_id, v3_user_id_list;
```

The above produces:

```
|----------+--------------|
| group_id | user_id_list |
|----------+--------------|
|      123 |          123 |
|          |          234 |
|          |          345 |
|          |          456 |
|          |          567 |
|          |          678 |
|      567 |          123 |
|          |          234 |
|          |          345 |
|          |          456 |
|          |          567 |
|          |          678 |
|----------+--------------|
```